# Can't use navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia in electron

Tags: typescript, electron

I want to get system audio output in electron, but when I use **navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia** in electron, recieved a error **"DOMException: Requested device not found"**, but it works in browser, this is my code

```
public onPrecess(fn: callBack) {
    navigator.mediaDevices
      // @ts-ignore
      .getDisplayMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true,
      })
      .then((stream: MediaStream) => {
        fn(stream)
      })
      .catch((err: string) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  }
```

What causes this problem?

Comment: If you just want to have audio and don't need video then try using just audio:true and set video:false.

Comment: thanks, but in this method, vedio: true is necessary

Comment: But if you need audio only why are you using getDisplayMedia() instead use getUserMedia().

Comment: I have tried, but it doesn't work on both environment, also recieved "DOMException: Requested device not found". I try to set only one option 'true', but it is useless, I guess getUserMedia() can only get a microphone or a camera source, because I don't have both of that device on my computer , so I decide to use getDisplayMedia ()

Answer (score 2):

Electron makes it easy to create a window and then load the specified web page to render. But if a web page includes WebRTC screen sharing logic, you'll find that Electron behaves differently than Chrome.
The problem is that Electron doesn't implement the getDisplayMedia interface for the Web RTC that Chrome supports, causing the screen that should pop out of the video stream selection to not display.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).