# navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia returning “NotAllowedError. Permission Denied” with electron

Tags: javascript, electron, screen-recording

I am trying to record the electron window.

I have been looking at the electron documentation that offers the option desktopCapturer, but then only uses “navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia”. I have read the documentation for getUserMedia and it says that it requests permissions for using input devices, such as the camera. But because this is not what I am trying to do, I realize that I actually need to use “navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia”.

When trying to use getDisplayMedia, it does not prompt me asking for permissions of screen recording, but it actually just rejects it. I have checked the security settings, and I’m actually allowing VS Code to record the screen.

I’d appreciate pointers to move forward from here.

This is basically the section of the code which is returning the error:

```
recordStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: {
          mediaSource: 'screen',

          // chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
          // chromeMediaSourceId: sourceId,
        },
      })
```

I have also seen this post here [Can't use navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914319/cant-use-navigator-mediadevices-getdisplaymedia-in-electron) but I am not sure if this still applies 5 years later.

If using getDisplayMedia is wrong, I still probably can use getUserMedia, but how could it do what I need it to do?